# Quartz scheduler running on multiple separate instances on server..one server shutdown

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, websphere-8, quartz

We are stuck with following issue.

We have WebSphere 8.5.7 silo architecture with 2 different instances for failover setup, having quartz scheduler (2.3.0) running as war on both, pointing to single Oracle database.

When one of instance of server is made shutdown for testing, what ever job running at that moment got blocked as seen on quartz_triggers tables. When 2nd silo starts picking up, it can't run job which is blocked though trigger timing reached. We have to run this job.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: its not about getting answers..its state of situation i am expressing.